How to implement an interval update in Dash when Dash app is integrated with Flask
I have a Dash graph integrated with the application in Flask. When I invoke Dash with the path /dash/ the graph is displayed. However, when there is an update to the data, the chart is not updated. I have read the documentation in Dash on how to implement a hot update, however I still don't understand how to implement it in my code. Which is integrated with Flask. I have read the section: Code Reloading & Hot Reloading I am aware that I have to implement the dash_app.callback function, how ever I have not idea where to include in the way my code is written.
@dash_app.callback(Output('create_dash_application', 'figure'),
[Input('interval_component', 'n_intervals')])

Here is the dcc.interval code that I have created, how ever I need to link that interval to the call back function.
dcc.Interval(id='interval_component', interval=200),                

Question: How can I implement the callback function in code that already works as expected?
Here is the screenshot of the chart generated by Dash:

Here is the section of my code in Dash:
from pkg_app import app

with app.app_context():

    # dash dependencies
    import dash
    from dash.dependencies import Output, Input    
    from dash import dcc
    from dash import html
    from flask_login.utils import login_required
    import plotly.express as px
    import pandas as pd

    # df for cola_de_atencion
    from pkg_app.pkg_models.User import User
    from pkg_app.pkg_models.Estado import Estado
    from pkg_app.pkg_models.Servicio import Servicio    
    from pkg_app.pkg_models.Cola_de_atencion import Cola_de_atencion
    
    turnos = Cola_de_atencion.query.all()

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            (t.id,
             t.user.username,
             t.turno_id,
             t.fecha,
             t.hora,
             t.estado.nombre,
             t.hora_atencion,
             t.tiempo_espera_recepcion,
             t.hora_finalizacion,
             t.tiempo_duracion_atencion,
             t.servicio.nombre)
            for t in turnos],
        columns=[
            'id',
            'ventanilla',
            'turno_id',
            'fecha',
            'hora',
            'estado',
            'hora_atencion',
            'tiempo_espera_recepcion',
            'hora_finalizacion',
            'tiempo_duracion_atencion',
            'servicio']
        )

    grp = df.groupby(['ventanilla','servicio'])
    

    lst_servicio   = []
    lst_cantidad   = []
    lst_ventanilla = []
    for name, group in grp:                
        lst_servicio.append(name[1])
        lst_cantidad.append(group.shape[0])
        lst_ventanilla.append(name[0])
    



    
    dfg = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Servicio": lst_servicio,
            "Amount": lst_cantidad,
            "Ventanilla": lst_ventanilla,
        }
    )
    

    def create_dash_application(flask_app):
        dash_app = dash.Dash(server=flask_app, name="Dashboard", url_base_pathname="/dash/")
        dash_app.layout = html.Div(
            children=[
                html.H1(children="Ventanilla x Turnos Atendidos"),
                html.Div(
                children="""
            En el eje X se despliegan las ventanillas, y en el eje Y se despliegan la cantidad de turnos atendidos por servicio.
        """
                ),
                # Needs the call back function 
                dcc.Interval(id='interval_component', interval=200),                

                dcc.Graph(
                    id="ventanilla_por_turnos",
                    figure=px.bar(dfg, x="Servicio", y="Amount", color="Ventanilla", barmode="group"),
                ),
             ]
          )

    
    for view_function in dash_app.server.view_functions:
        if view_function.startswith(dash_app.config.url_base_pathname):
            dash_app.server.view_functions[view_function] = login_required(
                dash_app.server.view_functions[view_function]
            )

    return dash_app

